# Override symfony TokenAuthenticator on phpunit tests

Tags: php, symfony, security, phpunit, symfony5

I have created a custom token authentication class by extending the AbstractGuardAuthenticator class as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html). My requirement was to accept a jwt, extract it and identify the user by check it's id against the database which is working completely fine.

Now I need to override underlying methods of it to use in **php unit tests**. In simple words, bypass it and set a default user. So I can test API end points without passing user tokens everytime when I do a functional test.

**What I tried**

I tried to defined a separate security.yaml in test folder and call customized class using it to override but still app calls the default class.

**Path:** *config/packages/test/security.yaml*

```
security:

  firewalls:

    main:
      anonymous: lazy
      logout: ~

      guard:
        authenticators:
          - Otrium\Infrastructure\Security\TestTokenAuthenticator
        entry_point: Otrium\Infrastructure\Security\TestTokenAuthenticator

      stateless: true
```

The only solution I found so far is to keep a matching jwt and pass it as a header value on each test.

Symfony version - 5 / Php version - 7.4

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override Authenticator.

You can find solution [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html#creating-the-authentication-token)

I used it in my project and I don't need to pass token in every request.